# Scrollview and nested scroll view not working

Tags: android, scrollview

> I am using scrollview like this way of layout inside scrollview and
>   nested scroll view both are not working

```
<RelativeLayout>
<scrollview>
 <LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout> 
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout> 
   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</scrollview>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

inside the scorll view i am trying fillviewport,scrollbar vertical like this also but it all not working. i am doing inside the fragment.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: this is my code layouts

Comment: Refer this one may help you.. your queation is not clear.. : https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview

Comment: We need to know what you mean by "not working." It would be easier for us to tell if your code were sufficient to reproduce the issue, but I assume it isn't since empty layouts will mean the scroll view doesn't need to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

It's Work Well In My Code,

You Can Try This:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            //Your Widgets....

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

           //Your Widgets....

        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: tq for your answer